# Am I seeing a particle orbiting a Morris-Thorne Wormhole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, metric-tensor, wormholes

I tried to calculate the time-like geodesics of the Morris-Thorne Wormhole $[1]$, $[2]$, $[3]$ for redshift function $\Phi(r) = 0$ and $b(r) = \sqrt{r_{0} r}$. But I don't know for sure if all the plots that I made are correct.

So, the metric is:

$$ds^2 = -e^{2\Phi(r)}dt^2+\Biggr\{ 1-\frac{b(r)}{r}\Biggr\}^{-1}dr^2+r^2[d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2]\tag{1}$$

And the plots are:

[image]

[image]

The various spheres are the 2-spheres due to spherical symmetry of the metric, and the central sphere is the sphere of the radius $r_{0}$, therefore is the throat.

My doubt is:

> Am I seeing a particle orbiting the throat of a Morris-Thorne Wormhole? In other words is it correct to say that the particle approches from infinity, orbits the throat and returns to the same universe?

$$ * * * $$

$[1]$ LOBO.F.S.N; *Exotic solutions in General Relativity*,arxiv:0710.4474v1, 2007

$[2]$ LOBO.F.S.N; *Wormholes, Warp Drives and Energy Conditions*,Springer, Vol.189, 2017

$[3]$ VISSER.M;   *Lorentzian Wormholes*, Springer, AIP Press, 1995

**Appendix: *Mathematica* code:**

I posted this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233860/am-i-seeing-a-particle-orbiting-a-morris-thorne-wormhole) as well, due to the mathamtica code.

```
n = Length[coords];
a = 0;
r0;
\[CapitalPhi][r] = 0;
B[r] = (Sqrt[r*r0]);

tt = -(Exp[
    2*\[CapitalPhi][
      r]   ]); rr = (1)/(1 - ((B[r])/(r))); \[Theta]\[Theta] = 
 r^2; \[CurlyPhi]\[CurlyPhi] = 
 r^2*(Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]); t\[CurlyPhi] = 0; metric = {{tt, 
   0, 0, 0}, {0, rr, 0, 0}, {0, 0, \[Theta]\[Theta], 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, \[CurlyPhi]\[CurlyPhi]}}; metric // MatrixForm
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]; inversemetric // MatrixForm
christoffel := 
 christoffel = 
  Simplify[Table[
    1/2*Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
        s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coords[[k]]] + 
         D[metric[[s, k]], coords[[j]]] \[Minus] 
          D[metric[[j, k]], coords[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
     1, n}, {k, 1, n}]]
listchristoffel := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[christoffel[[i, j, k]], 
     0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i, j, k]], 
     christoffel[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
    j}] TableForm[
   Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listchristoffel], Null], 2], 
   TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
geodesic := 
 geodesic = 
  Simplify[Table[\[Minus]Sum[
      christoffel[[i, j, k]] coords[[j]]' coords[[k]]', {j, 1, n}, {k,
        1, n}], {i, 1, n}]]
listgeodesic := 
 Table[{"d/d\[Tau]" ToString[coords[[i]]'], " =", geodesic[[i]]}, {i, 
   1, n}]
TableForm[listgeodesic, TableSpacing -> {2}]

max\[Tau] = 750; ivs = {0, 0, 0.088}; ics = {0, 6.5, \[Pi]/2, 
  0}; r0 = 1;
computeSoln[max\[Tau]i_, ivsi_, icsi_] := 
 Block[{ivs, ics, i, \[Chi], tmp, soln}, ics = icsi;
  ivs = Join[{\[Chi]}, ivsi];
  op1 = Table[coords[[i]] -> ics[[i]], {i, 0, n}];
  tm = metric /. op1;
  tmp = ivs.(tm.ivs); \[Chi]slv = Solve[tmp == uinvar, \[Chi]];
  ivs[[1]] = Last[\[Chi] /. \[Chi]slv];
  op = {Derivative[1][t] -> Derivative[1][t][\[Tau]], 
    Derivative[1][r] -> Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]], 
    Derivative[1][\[Theta]] -> Derivative[1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]], 
    Derivative[1][\[CurlyPhi]] -> Derivative[1][\[CurlyPhi]][\[Tau]], 
    t -> t[\[Tau]], 
    r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[CurlyPhi] -> \
\[CurlyPhi][\[Tau]]};
  deq = Table[
    coords[[i]]''[\[Tau]] == Simplify[geodesic[[i]] /. op], {i, 1, 
     n}]; deq = 
   Join[deq, Table[coords[[i]]'[0] == ivs[[i]], {i, 1, n}], 
    Table[coords[[i]][0] == ics[[i]], {i, 1, n}]];
  soln = NDSolve[deq, coords, {\[Tau], 0, max\[Tau]i}]; soln]
uinvar = \[Minus]1;
sphslnToCartsln[soln_] := 
 Block[{xs, ys, zs}, 
  xs = r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]] Cos[\[CurlyPhi][\[Tau]]] /. 
    soln; ys = 
   r[\[Tau]] Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi][\[Tau]]] /. soln;
  zs = r[\[Tau]] Cos[\[Theta][\[Tau]]] /. soln; {xs, ys, zs}]
udotu[solni_, \[Tau]val_] := 
 Block[{x\[Alpha], u\[Alpha]}, 
  x\[Alpha] = 
   Table[coords[[i]][\[Tau]] /. solni, {i, 1, n}] // Flatten;
  u\[Alpha] = D[x\[Alpha], \[Tau]];
  x\[Alpha] = x\[Alpha] /. \[Tau] -> \[Tau]val;
  u\[Alpha] = u\[Alpha] /. \[Tau] -> \[Tau]val;
  u\[Alpha].((metric /. 
       Table[coords[[i]] -> x\[Alpha][[i]], {i, 1, n}]).u\[Alpha])]
coordlist[\[Tau]in_] := 
 Table[ToString[coords[[i]]] <> 
   " = " <> {ToString[coords[[i]][\[Tau]in] /. soln // First]}, {i, 1,
    n}]

soln = computeSoln[max\[Tau], ivs, ics];

xyzsoln = sphslnToCartsln[soln];
Join[{"Final Coordinates:"}, coordlist[max\[Tau]]] // TableForm
Join[{{"", "", "", "u.u values"}}, 
  Table[{"\[Tau]=", ToString[i], "->", udotu[soln, i]}, {i, 0, 
    max\[Tau], max\[Tau]/5}]] // TableForm
{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[coords[[i]][\[Tau]] /. soln, {i, 1, n}]], {\[Tau], 0, 
   max\[Tau]}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "Coordinate"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"t", "r", "\[Theta]", "\[CurlyPhi]"}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 30}], 
 Show[ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{xyzsoln[[1]], xyzsoln[[2]]} // Flatten], {\[Tau], 0, 
    max\[Tau]}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Gray], 
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}]]}

Shape FUNCTION;

(1)/(((r)/((Sqrt[r*r0]))) - 1)

Integrate[(1)/(((r)/((Sqrt[r*r0]))) - 1), r]

max\[Tau] = 2000;
ivs = {\[Minus]0.08, .035, .0359};
ics = {0, 2, Pi/4, 0.2};
xyzsoln = sphslnToCartsln[computeSoln[max\[Tau], ivs, ics]];
angle = ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[Re[xyzsoln] // Flatten], {\[Tau], 0, max\[Tau]}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, DisplayFunction -> Identity];
sphhoriz = 
  SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-30, 30}}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", BoxRatios -> 2, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]];
sphhoriz2 = 
  SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 
    0, (3/2)*Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-30, 30}}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", BoxRatios -> 2, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]];
Show[angle, sphhoriz, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
Show[angle, sphhoriz2 , DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Comment: It’s spherically symmetric, so why not work in two spatial dimensions instead of three?

Comment: *I don't know for sure if all the plots that I made are correct.* As you probably know, check-my-work and check-my-code questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @G.Smith You can close the question if you want, I totally agree about the check-my-work status. But, I want to construct a 3D plot, and I really do not know if the interpretation is correct, about the 2-spheres, thought the geodesic is correct.

Comment: If we can say that the inner most sphere is in fact the Throat of the wormhole, then this graph is quite interesting, because we can see that this trajectory do not cross to the other asymptotic region.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for physics.stackexchange : it's not really about _Mathematica_ itself.

Comment: `coords` and `r0` are not defined  in your code.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to your initial conditions, which you didn’t describe. How can you draw any conclusion from only two simulations?

Comment: @G.Smith ivs = {\[Minus]0.08, .035, .0359};  ics = {0, 2, Pi/4, 0.2}; are the initial conditions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev max\[Tau] = 750; ivs = {0, 0, 0.088}; ics = {0, 6.5, \[Pi]/2, 
  0}; r0 = 1;

Comment: And, @AlexTrounev, I acknowledged you here: https://curvedrealityarxiv.files.wordpress.com/2020/09/schwarzschild-wormholes.pdf

Comment: It seems to me that this could either be orbiting the throat and returning to the same universe, or orbiting in the throat as one goes through it. I guess the latter is more likely, since the curvature tends to pull geodesics apart from each other unlike gravity. Not sure how to test the case except plotting what happens to r.

Comment: @M.N.Raia In Mathematica we can improve code. But what we can improve in Physics?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I do not understood your question.

Comment: @M.N.Raia You show us metric and code, but asking about particle orbit. How we know what equations do you use and what the problem you try to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I seeing a particle orbiting a Morris-Thorne Wormhole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591165/am-i-seeing-a-particle-orbiting-a-morris-thorne-wormhole)

Comment: Note: this question appears to have been cross-posted to both [physics.se] and [mathematica.se]; the mathematica version got migrated here, so we had two copies of the same question. Those two identical questions are now merged.